# How do I get accuracy while using Single class in KNN classifier

Tags: tensorflow, classification, knn

I am trying to classify images of known and unknown types.
KNN classifier in Tensorflow JS requires multiple classes in order to differentiate which is a near matching class.
I am only using a single class and any image sent to it shows confidence as 1 for the same class since there is only 1 class that exists.
How do I classify images based on the trained weights and percentage of accuracy against the trained data.

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this https://towardsdatascience.com/one-class-neural-network-in-keras-249ff56201c0

Comment: Yes, but the article requires upgraded version to access it.

Comment: To access what? It's just a conceptual method. You can apply it how you need.